# Como checar mudança em tempo real no banco de dados com websocket php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, websocket, pooling

Quero atualizar uma div somente quando houver mudança em um determinado campo no banco de dados, atualmente estou usando polling, mas quero mudar para websocket por questões de desempenho, mas só achei exemplos de chats, e não é o que eu preciso.
Alguém tem uma dica de como checar mudanças no bd com websocket?

Comment: Alguma dica pessoal?

Comment: Ampla demais sua pergunta. Antes de mais nada, já sabe usar websocket? Se não souber, melhor começar por aí, pois a parte do BD vem depois.

Comment: A resposta do @Inkeliz me parece apresentar no número 3 a melhor opção. Você tem algum motivo específico pra mandar as mensagens do websocket à nível de banco de dados e não de aplicação? Por que me parece contra-produtivo, especialmente no mysql que não está tão preocupado com tempo-real. Talvez usar o Redis ou o MongoDB sejam opções melhores nesse caso, mas vai depender das suas necessidades.

Answer (score 6):

Você tem várias maneiras.

1. **MySQL: Usando [`sys_exec()`](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme).**

   Ele pode ser usado como um `Trigger`, sempre que o dado é adicionado ele é acionado e portanto pode acionar um arquivo, como por exemplo um PHP, este PHP envia a informação via websocket.

   Maleficio: O PHP tende a ser lento e somado com o tempo de conexão você terá um *query* muito mais lenta, uma vez que ela somente irá terminar após o websocket ser concluído, ou você terá que fazer alguma gambiarra para executar *silenciosamente*, de qualquer uma das formas isto não estará mencionado no `EXPLAIN`, você pode não conseguir saber a razão do banco da dados está lento.

> [Encontrei esta publicação do PubNub](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043795-can-i-publish-a-message-via-a-database-trigger-), *uma empresa que oferece websockets*, que utiliza `curl` diretamente usando o `sys_eval()`, porém com uma "advertência" que isto não é recomendado.

2. **MySQL: Cheque os logs.**

   Você sabe como as replicas do MySQL são sincronizadas (um master + X slaves)? Uma das formas é sincronizando os logs do *master*, nele contem tudo que foi mudado e você pode utilizar os isto para ver o que mudou e enviar informações baseada nela. Essa solução talvez seja a mais complexa (e menos clara) na minha opinião, você também pode usar algo como `inotifywait` para acionar quando o arquivo for atualizado.
3. **PHP: Envie depois do `commit`.**

   Imagine que você tem um website que possua um saldo, transferível entre usuários, você quer notifica-los quando cada um receber e enviar, **por exemplo**:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($con);
mysqli_autocommit($con, false);

$detalhe = mysqli_query($con, '
   INSERT INTO `pagamento_detalhe`(`QuemPagou`, `QuemRecebeu`, `Valor`) 
     VALUES ("'.$idPagou.'", "'.$idRecebeu.'", "'.$Valor.'")
');
$detalhe = mysqli_affected_rows($con) === 1;

$atualizaSaldo = mysqli_query($con, '
   UPDATE usuario as Pagou, usuario as Recebeu 
    SET Pagou.Saldo = Pagou.Saldo - '.$Valor.', Recebeu.Saldo = Recebeu.Saldo + '.$Valor.' 
     WHERE Pagou.id = "'.$idPagou.'" AND Recebeu.id = "'.$idRecebeu.'"
');
$atualizaSaldo = mysqli_affected_rows($con) === 2;

if($atualizaSaldo && $detalhe){
    mysqli_commit($con);
}else{
    mysqli_rollback($con);
}
```

Seria mais fácil adicionar algo deste tipo:

```
//...
if($atualizaSaldo && $detalhe){
    mysqli_commit($con);
    enviar_websocket($idPagou, 'Você enviou '.$Valor);
    enviar_websocket($idRecebeu, 'Você recebeu '.$Valor);
}else{
    mysqli_rollback($con);
}
```

Criando uma função `enviar_websocket` irá enviar o `websocket` para o `id` correspondente com uma mensagem que você define, POR EXEMPLO. Isso será enviado sempre que ocorrer uma atualização dos dados, porém ainda no lado do PHP e não do MySQL.

Comment: Olá Murilo Souza. Conseguiu resolver? Estou precisando exatamente disso e como você só tenho encontrado exemplos de chat. Se conseguiu, tem como compartilhar sua solução? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa identificar quem faz o update, delete ou insert no seu banco, provavelmente um arquivo .php deve fazer isso, considerando isto, alguma máquina client solicitou esse arquivo, correto?

Considerando que vc já tenha um servidor websocket funcionando é só mandar um send()"javascript" para o socketID da maquina client que deseja receber essa alteração.

Para detalhe sobre como montar servidor websocket, tenho um totalmente em php e posso te ajudar, não é difícil, existem vários tutos que ensina a montar um como chat, é só adaptar ao seu uso. veja esse link
 http://gustavobeavis.github.io/blog/2014/09/11/web-socket-php/

Me baseei nele para montar um chat interno para empresa onde trabalho...