# Dúvida: Web Sockets e como usar

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, node.js

Estava vendo essa pergunta [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193634/como-checar-mudan%C3%A7a-em-tempo-real-no-banco-de-dados-com-websocket-phphttps://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193634/como-checar-mudan%C3%A7a-em-tempo-real-no-banco-de-dados-com-websocket-php).

Então no li na resposta sobre nodeJS e pesquisei sobre, porém nao entendi muito.
Como aplicar essa tecnologia (nodeJS)?
Estou desenvolvendo um site em php/jquery e nele tenho painel administrativo com um menu que contém um `badge`, então criei uma função ajax que executa a cada 3 segundos e se tem alteração no banco ele me notifica neste `badge`. Li que isso sobrecarrega o servidor.

Eis a dúvida:

Como fazer da forma mais correta essa notificação?
Se possível, algum exemplo explicativo aonde a alteração do banco de dados ou identificando a ação do usuário no site, atualize essa minha notificação (`badge`) no painel administrativo.

Comment: Nenhuma resposta??!!